# How do i check what is the kind of an element from a data type variable in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a data type like this:

```
data Token = Foo | Bar | Number Int deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And a variable:

```
a = Number 20
```

How can i test if this variable is a Number? Its type is Token, but i would like to see if it can work as an int.

Answer (score 6):

You use pattern matching. An an example, here's a simple predicate that will return `True` if it's a value created by `Number`, and `False` otherwise.

```
isNumber :: Token -> Bool
isNumber (Number _) = True
isNumber _ = False
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chepner has already given how to test whether a `Token` value uses the `Number` constructor or not. But I feel a bit more can be said about how to extract the `Int` value from it, which seems to be what you want when you say you "would like to see if it can work as an int.". Because if you use chepner's `isNumber` function and it returns `True`, you can't get that `Int` out without pattern matching once again. So you might as well combine the two steps into one.

Here is a simple way to do that:

```
getNumber :: Value -> Maybe Int
getNumber (Number n) = Just n
getNumber _ = Nothing
```

Notice the type here - this function can't return an `Int` because you don't know that the value you're testing on contains one!* Notice also how similar it is in structure with the `isNumber` function - and this still allows you easily to do different things with the different cases, like this

```
case (getNumber someValue) of
  Just n -> - - do something with n
  Nothing -> - - handle the other cases
```

Note that this assumes you want to handle all non-numeric constructors the same way. If you want to do something different with each, then you don't need `getNumber` or `isNumber` but can just pattern match directly on `someValue` and do whatever you need in each case.

*you might want to provide a default in this case, like 0. But even then I would suggest using the same `getNumber` function above and combining it with the library function `fromMaybe` - ie `getWithDefault = fromMaybe 0 . getNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

The data type itself already tells you what it is. So you *use* it *as an `Int`* like this:

```
foo :: (Int -> r) -> Token -> Maybe r
foo f (Number i) = Just (f i)
foo _  _         = Nothing
```

In case it was an `Int`, we use it; and otherwise, we don't.